# maximum number of transactions in memory pool

Tags: txpool

Is there a maximum number of transactions that can sit in the Monero memory pool at the same time?

If there is, what happens to transactions that would cause the memory pool to exceed that level of capacity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the amount of RAM/swap you have.

There is no code to stop accepting transactions at any point at the moment, and if you eat up all you can in a spam attack, your kernel will kill bitmonerod. If that happens, you get to restart it, with more swap. If your node was the one the transaction was sent by the wallet, that transasction is nowhere else. If you were sent that transasction by another node, that node still has it, and it presumably got relayed to other nodes as well.

A transaction should not take much more RAM than its binary representation, but it's a bit hard to give an exact figure, since we're talking about std::map overhead, etc. So if you can afford half a gigabyte for the txpool, then, at an average tx size of 4 kB, you get...125k txes ?